# how to insert cases into a table based on a parameter without duplicating the main select query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a insert statement in sql server 2008 like below:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE
SELECT Id,Name,Date
FROM #temp
...joins...
where ...conditions...
```

I need to add a parameter to the code, and based on the parameter I will decide which table the output data should be inserted into. Check below:

```
declare @checkValue bit;
if (@checkValue = 1)
begin
   INSERT INTO MYTABLE
    SELECT Id,Name,Date
    FROM #temp
    ...joins...
    where ...conditions...
end
else
begin
    INSERT INTO MY_OTHER_TABLE
    SELECT Id,Name,Date
    FROM #temp
    ...joins...
    where ...conditions...
end
```

I handled the situation like above for now, however the main query is pretty long and I do not want to duplicate it, it does not look professional to me. I am looking for a better way to deal with such an issue. Any help or advice should be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is it nessasary to use #temp table? Without it you can use table-valued functions

Comment: yes it is, actually with the joins there are more then 20 tables in the original query, some of them temprorary tables some of them permanent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use dynamic SQL (evil :), like so:

```
declare @cmd varchar(max) = '
INSERT INTO ' + @tableName + '
SELECT ...
';

execute (@cmd);
```

Or you create stored procedures (one statically INSERTs to table A, another one into table B >> code duplication) which are called depending on @checkValue, or a combination of both like here:

[Stored procedure to insert values into dynamic table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586842/stored-procedure-to-insert-values-into-dynamic-table)

Answer (score 0):

create SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ExampleSelect
AS
    SELECT Id,Name,Date
    FROM #temp
    ...joins...
    where ...conditions...
GO
```

use insert..exec to insert data:

```
declare @checkValue bit;
if (@checkValue = 1)
begin
   INSERT INTO MYTABLE
   EXEC ExampleSelect
end
else
begin
    INSERT INTO MY_OTHER_TABLE
    EXEC ExampleSelect
end
```